# How to change not operand behaviour

Tags: python, class

I dont know if this is posible but I want something like this pseudo code:

```
switch='.csv'
switch= not switch
print(switch) 
#output=.json
switch=not switch 
print(switch) 
#output =.csv
```

I've been reading about overrinding the `__bool__` dunder method or the `__neg__` dunder method but honestly I don't have any idea on how to actually make it real...I want to do this just to understand better how classes works not necesarily to apply it to a project.

Comment: Overloads are done in user-defined classes. You shouldn't redefine the behavior of built-in types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar pointed out, you'll need to define a user-defined class to make it real using dunder methods.

`__bool__` will not work here because the return value of the bool method must have type `bool` (i.e. be `True` or `False`) (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__)). But you can use `-` by implementing the `__neg__` method on a user-defined class:

```
class FileExt:

    def __init__(self, value):

        self.val = value

    def __repr__(self):

        # When class instance is printed, print val attribute
        return self.val

    def __neg__(self):

        if self.val == '.csv':
            return FileExt('.json')
        elif self.val == '.json':
            return FileExt('.csv')
        else:
            raise ValueError("self.val should be '.csv' or '.json'")


my_file_ext = FileExt('.csv')
my_file_ext = -my_file_ext
print(my_file_ext)
my_file_ext = -my_file_ext
print(my_file_ext)
```

Output:

```
.json
.csv
```

It is important to remember that my_file_ext now has type `FileExt`, so certain basic operations may not work as expected. For example, I guess you are likely to want to concatenate the file extensions to other strings to make file names, etc., but with the above class definition this won't work:

```
my_file_ext = FileExt('.csv')
print('my_file' + my_file_ext)
```

outputs

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "FileExt") to str
```

To replicate string concatenation, you'd need to define the `__add__` and `__radd__` methods by adding the following to the class declaration:

```
    def __add__(self, any_string):

        if isinstance(any_string, str):
            return self.val + any_string
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Can't add {self.__name__} instance to non-string value!")

    def __radd__(self, any_string):

        if isinstance(any_string, str):
            return any_string + self.val
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Can't add {self.__name__} instance to non-string value!")
```

Now,

```
my_file_ext = FileExt('.csv')
print('my_file' + my_file_ext)
```

outputs

```
my_file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for and trying to understand